# How to make floated div container fit to the div height?

Tags: html, css

I have a div container `#parent` and a div child `#child` who's child of the parent div .

The `#child` div contain text and he is floated left, the problem is that I want the `#parent` div to fit the height of the #child` div what ever the height is with keeping the float property also .

```css
    #parent{
       background: red;
       height: auto;
    }

    #child{
       float:left;
    }
```

```html
    <div id='parent'>
        <div id='child'>
           <p>Some text Some text Some text</p>
        </div>  
    
    </div>
```

Here is a [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/460/)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add `overflow:auto` to the parent:

```
#parent {
    background: red;
    height: auto;
    overflow:auto;
}
#child {
    float:left;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/XgErJ/462/)**

When you float the child, the parent collapses because it's acting as if the child occupies no space. Adding the overflow rule restores the behavior that you're after.

Answer (score 2):

Method :1

```
 #parent{
       background: red;
       height: auto;
       overflow:auto
    }

    #child{
       float:left;
      }
```

http://jsbin.com/yufezamofo/3/

Method:2

```
 #parent{
       background: red;
       height: auto;
display:table
    }

    #child{
       float:left;
      display:table-cell;
      }
```

http://jsbin.com/yufezamofo/2/

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/461/)

One way to do it is with ":after" selector.

HTML

```
<div id='parent'>

    <div id='child'>
       <p>Some text Some text Some text</p>
    </div>  

</div>
```

CSS

```
#parent{
   background: red;
}
#parent:after {
   content:'';
   display:block;
   clear: both;
}
#child{
   float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use clearfix.

```
.clearfix:after {
             visibility: hidden;
             display: block;
             font-size: 0;
             content: " ";
             clear: both;
             height: 0;
    }
.clearfix { 
   display: inline-block; 
    }
            /* start commented backslash hack \*/
    * html .clearfix { 
     height: 1%; 
    }
    .clearfix { 
    display: block; 
    }
      /* close commented backslash hack */
```

http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/463/